# Coldfusion 10 error: Unable to store Job... because one already exists with this identification

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am getting the following error all of a sudden on a CF10 application that was working fine for the last couple of days, but is now just showing this error:

***Unable to store Job : 'SERVERSCHEDULETASK#$%^DEFAULT.job_CHECKQUOTEEXPIRATION', because one already exists with this identification.***

The schedule code looks like this:

```
<cfschedule action = "update" 
    task = "CheckQuoteExpiration"  
    operation = "HTTPRequest" 
    url = "#application.Config.scheduleTaskUrl#CheckQuotesExpiration" 
    startDate = "2012-01-01" 
    startTime = "11:59 PM" 
    interval = "daily" 
    requestTimeOut = "600">
```

From what I can see, maybe it is erroring when trying to recreate the scheduled task, but why? And how do I resolve this?

[I would just like to add that this is occuring on a shared hosting envirnoment at Hostek]

Thanks

Comment: Try a delete/create instead?

Comment: @BenKoshy: I shouldn't have to do that - the whole point of an update is that it updates the schedule if it exists, or it creates it if it doesn't. It should not be doing this unless there is a bug in Coldfusion, which I suspect is the case here.

Comment: @cheeky is right; from CF 10 docs: update: Updates an existing task or creates a task, if one with the name specified by the task attribute does not exist.

Comment: 'SERVERSCHEDULETASK#$%^DEFAULT.job_CHECKQUOTEEXPIRATION' is an odd name in the error though.  I would think that "CheckQuoteExpiration" would have been displayed.  How does the job appear in CF Admin?

Comment: Deleting the schedule from the administrator worked, but unfortunately it doesn't actually explain what the problem is or prevent it from happening again in future.

Comment: And just for the record (this error just occurred again), doing a cfschedule action="delete" on the task before running the cfschedule action="update" errors as well - stating that the task does not exist.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this Cheeky?

Comment: @Lucas: Unfortunately not.

Comment: @ScottJibben: I'm not sure how the task appears in the admin as it is running on shared instance at Hostek, who have also not been able to shine any light on the issue.